# Directive to traverse a dropdown list using keyboard arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a bootstrap dropdown as follows:

```
 <span class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Boot Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li keyArrows *ngFor="let option of listOptions [class.select]="listOption==option" (click)="listOption=option">{{option.title}}</li>
  </ul>
 </span>
```

When I hit enter, the dropdown opens, but I cannot traverse through the items in the list with keyboard up and down arrows. I would like to implement that using an Angular 2 directive.

I did the following:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[keyArrows]"
})
export class KeyArrows implements OnDestroy {
    private arrows;
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.arrows = function (event) {
           switch(event.which){
               case 37: //left
               console.log("Left arrow triggered");
               break;

               case 38: //up
                var target = $(event.target).prev();
                $(target).trigger('focus');
               console.log("Up arrow triggered");
               break;

               case 39: //right
               console.log("right arrow triggered");
               break;

               case 40: //down
               var target = $(event.target).next();
               $(target).trigger('focus');
               console.log("down arrow triggered");
               break;

               default: return; //exit handler for other keys
           }

           event.preventDefault();
        }
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.arrows, false);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.arrows, false);
    }
}
```

Currently, the directive doesn't work as I am missing something crucial in this which I am unable to figure out.

I was wondering if someone could help me out with their expertise on how to achieve this kind of a task or point me in a right direction or comment on whatever I have written here.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey did you ever make progress on this? If not, can you make a simple example on a site like plnkr, jsbin, etc?

Comment: I was able to modify the angular tutorial [hero example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-1/ts/plnkr.html) plunker and add in your keyarrows directive - see [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LJQQjLGjOd3A2vBfz2za?p=preview) - does that help you at all, or did you already get something like that working?